# angular js conditional filtering?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to disable the filter when I select the "all" option for my select ng-model.

Here's the code:

```
Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
Search By: 
<select ng-model="queryBy">
    <option value="$">all</option>
    <option value="1">category 1</option>
    <option value="2">category 2</option>
    <option value="3">category 3</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchText | filter: {category: queryBy}"></li>
</ul>
```

When I select the first option ("$"), I want the filter to be disabled. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Just figured it out myself. I just had to change the "$" to ""

Comment: Then put it as an answer to this question, SO explicitly encourage users to answer their own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out myself. I just had to change the "$" to "", an empty string. 
Since an empty string doesn't specify a filter criteria, a filter isn't applied. 
So the revised code would be:

```
<select ng-model="queryBy">
<option value="">all</option>
<option value="1">category 1</option>
<option value="2">category 2</option>
<option value="3">category 3</option>
```